# Regular expression is not working with single character

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write regular expression in `Java` to evaluate two strings mentioned with () separated by ,

```
Example: (test1,test2)
```

I have written below code

```
public static void main(String[] a){
    String pattern = "\\([a-zA-Z0-9]+,[a-zA-Z0-9]+.\\)";
    String test = "(test1,test2)";
    System.out.println(test.matches(pattern));
}
```

It works as expected and prints `true` in below cases

```
String test = "(test1,test2)";

String test = "(t,test2)";
```

But it is printing `false` when I send below

```
String test = "(test1,t)";
```

It is strange because I am using same expression before and after ,

It returns `true` for `(t,test2)` but not for `(test1,t)`

Please let me know what am I missing in this regular expression. I need it to evaluate and return `true` for `(test1,t)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no need for the `.` (that matches one character) in your regex. Remove `.` from your regex so it becomes `"\\([a-zA-Z0-9]+,[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)"` and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

Use this regex:

```
String pattern = "^\\(.+,.+\\)";
```

This will match your required strings.

Answer (score 2):

In the second part of your pattern, you have `"[a-zA-Z0-9]+."`

If you're trying to match `"t"`, it will see `t` for the `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` part, but it requires another character after that to match the `.` part.

Revised pattern: `"\\([a-zA-Z0-9]+,[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)"`

Answer (score 2):

Delete the dot after the second group[a-zA-Z0-9]

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rfrUrg/1)

Answer (score 2):

and even simpler you can use \w for words, you can use instead of [a-zA-Z0-9]

so your regular expression would be like that

```
\(\w+,\w+\)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your regular expression '.' is not needed in the latter part. 
change is as "\([a-zA-Z0-9]+,[a-zA-Z0-9]+\)" so that it will be returning true for "(test,t)"

```
String pattern = "\\([a-zA-Z0-9]+,[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)";
String test = "(te,t)";
System.out.println(test.matches(pattern)); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String pattern = "\\([a-zA-Z0-9]+,[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)";
String test = "(test1,test2)";
String t1 = "(t,test2)";
String t2="(test2,t)";
System.out.println(test.matches(pattern));
System.out.println(t1.matches(pattern));
System.out.println(t2.matches(pattern));
```

just try this code, it will give you answer  you want.

You have written "." at the end after +  in your pattern so clear it.